# How to use getter and setter on multiple class

Tags: java

I have a 3 class 1 for a and b and the other one for GetterAndSetter so im having a problem on getting the string value of username it gives me null what is wrong with my code?

```
class A {

    JTextfield txt;

    public A() {
        txt = new JTextField();
        String userName = txt.getText();
        GetterAndSetter gs = new GetterAndSetter();
        gs.setUsername(userName);
    }
}

class B {

    JTextField txt2;

    public B(GetterAndSetter gs) {
        txt2 = new JTextField();
        txt2.setText(gs.getUsername());
    }
}

public class GetterAndSetter{

    private String whatName;

    public void setUsername(String userName) {
        whatName = userName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return whatName;
    }
}
```

Comment: `String userName = txt1.getText();` ? First clarify your question..

Comment: *what is wrong with my code?* It doesn't compile.

Comment: I just shortened it sorry. example the user enters a username in the textfield and I want to use that username to other class but im always getting null value.

Comment: The text will always be null. You initialise the text field and then try and get the text.

Comment: so pass as obj to other class..

Comment: @Xiaoxoo check the value of username in class a.

Comment: @bwfcwalshy what am i suppose to do? Im stuck in this part :(

Comment: Well I don't know what your program does but if you want them to enter a username have a text field and a submit button or something like that. Check when that is clicked by using addActionListener and then call the set username and do the rest of the code.

Comment: @Xiaoxoo you just replace the String userName = this.txt1.getText(); to String userName = "check"; if it works then problem is getting the value of textfield

Comment: @Xiaoxoo Okay you really need to write with interpunction if there are no dots or commas within the sentences it is really hard to read for people do you understand me or not

Comment: Hi. This question is *horrible*. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit this question... It is not clear what you are trying to achieve nor how you are running this code, nor what you are expecting. How do you expect people to understand your problem? This question is a perfect example of *how not to ask a question on SO*.  Other than that: this code is flawed on so many levels, you clearly are in over your head. I srsly recommend starting with something easier than this......

Answer (score 0):

At this point

```
txt = new JTextField();
String userName = txt.getText();
```

`userName` is empty, since you filled it from an empty, freshly-created text field.
Right after that

```
GetterAndSetter gs = new GetterAndSetter();
gs.setUsername(userName);
```

You set the empty string into a `GetterAndSetter` instance, but the poor lonely `gs` instance is not used anywhere and ends up in the void of java garbage collector.

Otherwise, I expect `GetterAndSetter` class to work correctly.

Also it seems that you forgot to include the code that actually uses class `A` and `B`. As of now, I have no idea what you were trying to accomplish, how were the classes supposed to interact together.